# Responsive Table with images

Tags: responsive-design, css-tables

I would like to resize two images (left image - right image) and maintain both on the same line. Now if I try to modify the window size the one on the right goes below the one on left.

[Example: Table with the two images - left sidebar](http://www.birikina.it/k/)

Seems that using a table can be the solution but I don't know how to make it responsive. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a table just to align content.  Tables are meant to display tabular(grid-type) data, not for layout.

If you have multiple elements in the DOM next to each other an easy approach is to set them each to `display: inline-block` which allows them to flow next to each other like inline elements but be styled as block level elements.

Because they are inline like text you can set `vertical-align: top` on both to align them to each other's top line regardless of height.  This also has an advantage over the use of floats in that they take up space in the parent element as well.